# android device doesn't show in device manager, error with Kies

Tags: driver, device, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to connect a Galaxy 2. The problem is, I can't get the device to show in the device manager. I found some explanations online that include "Go to the Samsung Kies, to Tools -> Install driver. So I went to Tools, and it doesn't have a "install driver" option. So I went to the Kies help, and there too it said to go to Tools -> Install Driver. BRAINFUCK! What's wrong with my Kies?!?

These are the instructions I followed:

Disconnected my phone from USB
Using USBDeview, I deinstalled all previously installed drivers relating to the phone (Careful here!)
Installed Samsung Kies, and loaded it
From Samsung Kies, I selected Tools > Install Driver (This step took a while, and it seemed like it had stalled – Be patient!)
Connected my phone to USB
The devices installed – Windows then gave me an error regarding missing drivers, however, when I checked device manager, I could see ‘Samsung Android Phone’ under which was ‘Samsung Android ADB Device’
I then ran ‘adb.exe devices’ (From a command prompt – adb.exe lives in the android-sdk folder) – This listed my device! Hoorah!

The first step was the bummer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: Settings->app settings->developing->enable first option

Comment: where is the 'settings' option located? in Kies?

Comment: Well.. as it turns out, I thought this was already enabled because it had a V next to it.. I didn't know the V had to be green (it's my girlfriend's phone, not mine, and I blame her!)

Comment: it's not constructive that you blame your girlfriend for not having green Vs on her phone. show her some peace, man! ;)